# once you select an item on a multiselect html listbox, is there anyway to deselect all

Tags: html, select

My users can't seem to deselect all on a select in html.  I have a basic multiselect listbox in html:

```
 <select class="longDropdown" id="SelectedCalendars"
         multiple="multiple" name="SelectedCalendars">
     <option value="13">ER</option>
     <option selected="selected" value="26">Billy 123</option>
     <option selected="selected" value="28">New Cal</option>
 </select>
```

if a few items start out selected, you can change by clicking on others to remove the selection,  but there doesn't seem to be a way for a user to deselect them all.  do i really have to write some jquery / javascript code to do this programatically.  Is this a flaw in the HTML UI spec?

Comment: You can't just hold Ctrl + click?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On macOS, the user can <kbd>⌘</kbd> + click on the last selected item to deselect it. On other platforms, the user would use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + click instead.

Comment: `Ctrl + click` in _Chrome + OSx_ opens the _context menu_ :/

Comment: Ok.. in _OSx_ is `cmd + click`:)