# How can I unselect an option from a multi select on a click ONLY if it is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a multi select element and once I select an option on it, is it then impossible to unselect all the options. 
I need to unselect the option when I click it and it was previously selected.

I have tried a few things but they don't work because everytime i click the option it becomes selected whether it was or not so its impossible to know if it was previously selected and should be unselected or if its the first time i am clicking it to select it

http://jsfiddle.net/JRgdv/

```
<select  multiple="multiple">
    <option>11111</option>
    <option selected>2</option>
    <option>33333</option>
    <option>44444</option>
</select>
```

I know I can have  button or an area that i can click to clear the whole thing but i am truying to make it so that if you click a selected option then it unselects it

edit: CTRL+Click is not what i am looking for. it has to be with the mouse only

Comment: As far as it goes, the browser can already unselect it if you `Ctrl+click`.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887128/once-you-select-an-item-on-a-multiselect-html-listbox-is-there-anyway-to-desele

Comment: Your edit: _CTRL+Click is not what i am looking for. it has to be with the mouse only_ is confusing.. It is a multi-selectbox and the user is going to use ctrl to select multiple items.

Comment: May be, user can click and drag to select multiple options...

Comment: This is annoying that there is no real solution for this! @code5788441441 is correct this is bad ui for force a keyboard interaction just to select more than one item. What about mobile? What about accessibility?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Could be a workaround:

[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JRgdv/3/)

```
$('select option').on('mousedown', function (e) {
    this.selected = !this.selected;
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

EDIT: this doesn't work on IE (version???). For cross browser solution, even uggly, try that instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21797607/1414562

Comment: Doesn't work properly if there are lots of option values, there is scrolling issue when you click.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a little hack-ish, but it works. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/JRgdv/1/

```
var currentSelect = $("select option:selected").index();

$("select option").click(function() {
    if ($(this).index() == currentSelect) {
        $(this).prop("selected", false);
        currentSelect = -1;
    } else {
        currentSelect = $(this).index();
    }
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work if more than one option was originally highlighted.

Comment: @j08691 -- Is there a way around this efficiently...all I can really think of now is make an array, push selected values to it..on click, search the array, if the values found, pop it, remove selected.