# mousedown event on options in select is not working in IE, Is there any workaround?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser, mouseevent

This following code snippet is to avoid the need for ctrl-click in a multi-select box

but it does not work in IE 8 .

Is there any work around to achive the same in IE and other IE version?

```
$('option').mousedown(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).prop('selected', !$(this).prop('selected'));
  return false;
});
```

Comment: `$(this).prop('selected', !$(this).prop('selected'));` Wow, what a long-winded and inefficient way to write `this.selected = !this.selected;` ;-)

Comment: No in IE8 its not working :( but works in both Chrome and Mozilla

Comment: Even in IE10, not working

Comment: So whats your point? Is it because    $(this).prop('selected', !$(this).prop('selected')); failing in IE ???

Comment: @monda: No, that's unrelated.

Comment: @T.J Crowder : I dint get you.. can u explain more.. why its failing in IE

Comment: @monda your issue depends of specific implementation of select element native to each browser. IE handles it differently making your workaround useless. Better would be to implement your own customized SELECT control. I'll check if there is some known workaround to still use native SELECT instead

Comment: so if  "mousedown not working for option element in IE" then what is the solution ? can you think any ?

Comment: @monda like i told you, best solution would be to implement customized SELECT control. I have checked, IE doesn't fire event on option, just on SELECT. Even using event bound to SELECT, it is not possible to target which OPTION has been clicked. So i'm out of idea regarding a cross-browser workaround using native SELECT element

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe there's any way to get the `mousedown` or `click` event on an `option` element in IE8.

If you really want the behavior you describe, I suggest that you use a different control, rather than a multiple `select` box. *Changing* the behavior of standard UI components is usually not a good idea, as users are used to them behaving a certain way and get confused when they behave differently in some apps/pages than they do in others. If you want a list with simple click-on, click-off behavior, much better to do something completely your own.

You *can* do this with a multiple `select`, but the user experience is really ugly:

```
var selected = {};
$('#yourSelectBox').click(function(e) {
    var $this = $(this),
        options = this.options,
        option,
        value,
        n;

    // Find out what option was just added
    value = $this.val();

    // Re-apply the selections
    for (n = 0; n < options.length; ++n) {
        option = options[n];
        if (option.value == value) {
            // The one being updated
            selected[value] = !selected[value];
        }

        // One of the others
        option.selected = !!selected[option.value];
    }

    return false;
});
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/kuneg/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/kuneg/1/edit)

Again, though, that's a really ugly user experience.

---

Here's an example of a pseudo-select instead: [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/kuneg/2/) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/kuneg/2/edit)

CSS:

```
.pseudo-select {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 200px;
}
.pseudo-option {
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
}
.pseudo-option.selected {
    background-color: #33c;
    color: white;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="pseudo-select">
    <div class="pseudo-option" data-value="1">One</div>
    <div class="pseudo-option" data-value="2">Two</div>
    <div class="pseudo-option" data-value="3">Three</div>
    <div class="pseudo-option" data-value="4">Four</div>
    <div class="pseudo-option" data-value="5">Five</div>
    <div class="pseudo-option" data-value="6">Six</div>
    <div class="pseudo-option" data-value="7">Seven</div>
    <div class="pseudo-option" data-value="8">Eight</div>
    <div class="pseudo-option" data-value="9">Nine</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript using jQuery:

```
$(".pseudo-option").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
});
```

That's just something I dashed off in a couple of minutes, obviously plenty of room for improvement, but you get the idea.

**Note**: If you use something like this, you'll want to detect mobile browsers and browsers using assisstive technologies (screen readers, etc.) and use a normal `select` instead (as the browser will do a better job of working with the user in those situations.).

Comment: Wow, that's an uggly but functional workaround, nice!

Comment: @A.Wolff: Yeah, big time. :-) I added an example of a pseudo-select as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found one major issue with jQuery answer above. The `.val()` of the `$(select)` won't update.

Here is working solution:

```
$select.mousedown(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const select = this;
    const { scrollTop } = select;
    e.target.selected = !e.target.selected;
    setTimeout(function () {
        select.scrollTop = scrollTop;
    }, 0);
}).mousemove(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); });
```